# Android SQLite column and index best practice

Tags: android, sqlite

I am starting to use SQLite in my Android app.  I'm not new to databases, I have many years do database work with Delphi which does take some of the work out of using databases.

In an app, one may have a table with several columns. When reading data out of the table one executes some SQL, then uses a cursor to access the data.

There are a couple of methods on the cursor to access the data, one uses the column index in the table - many of the examples I've seen on the net use this.  For example:

```
cursor.getString(3);
```

Having the "3" embedded in code is not the greatest idea, so you can use:

```
int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex( "THECOLUMNNAME" );
cursor.getString(idx);
```

Using getColumnIndex() more than once for a table and column is wasteful.  Keeping constants of the indexes of what could be several 10s or 100s of columns is prone to error.

My question is - what is the best practice for doing this sort of thing?

Should I extend Cursor to better represent a specific table?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: IMO, having a table with "100s of columns" is a sign for bad table design. Especially for a mobile application.

Comment: using getColumnIndex is the best practice for doing this..

Comment: OK - 100s of columns across many tables is what I meant. It is still 100s of column indexes to keep track of.

Comment: @ Volodymyr - how often would you call getColumnIndex for a given query?  Do you cache the column index, or waste time parsing the string each time?  If you cache the index, do you write code to do it for every query, or do you extend the cursor or something else to keep track of the index so you only have to write the code once?  I think the question is deeper than just using getColumnIndex(). Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have very few columns, and especially when those columns do not have proper names (like `SELECT MAX(x), MIN(x) FROM t`), using fixed column indexes is perfectly fine.
This is more dangerous when it is likely that the number/order of columns will change later, or when there is a large distance between the query and the cursor accesses in the source code.

If you want to avoid too many `getColumnIndex` calls, you should indeed cache the return value.
This can be made easier with a wrapper class that contains both the column index and a reference to the cursor, like this:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
Field foo = new Field(cursor, "FOO");
Field bar = new Field(cursor, "BAR");
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    foo.getString();
    bar.getInteger();
}
```

(The implementation of this class is left as an exercise ...)

Answer (score 1):

In at least some implementations of Cursor, getColumnIndex iterates through an array of column names (see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#AbstractCursor.getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) for one example.) If your query involves a table with a large number of columns, you might want to cache the column indexes before you loop through the rows in the result.

But as others pointed out in comments, a large number of columns may be a symptom of poor database design.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that link.  Again I'll say - it did not mean a large number of columns in one table, but an app that has sevarl tables can easily have a 100 columns.  I have worked with well normalised databases where tables have 10s of columns.  I think I'll edit the original post to make the point.