# How to index one column when use full text search in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Fts3 in sqlite use virtual table, that mean it use memory(ram) to store data? I have a table and only want to index one column, but fts3 require index all table, do that make increase the store data? How to index one column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SQLite column and index best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408348/android-sqlite-column-and-index-best-practice)

Comment: It 's not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "virtual" just means that such a table is not a 'normal' SQLite table but has a custom implementation.

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_9_1) says:

> For each FTS virtual table in a database, three to five real (non-virtual) tables are created to store the underlying data. These real tables are called "shadow tables". The real tables are named "%_content", "%_segdir", "%_segments", "%_stat", and "%_docsize", where "%" is replaced by the name of the FTS virtual table.

An FTS table should be thought of as an index, not a table.
You should keep your original table, and put only the text column into an FTS table. (To avoid duplicate storage, you can use an [external content table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_6_2_2).)